# Magento: Remove "powered by Turnkey Linux" from footer

Tags: magento-1.7, footer

I am trying to remove the "Magento Appliance - Powered by TurnKey Linux" link in the footer of my magento webshop without any luck.

Here is what I tried already:

1. Backend:CMS>Static blocks
2. App>Design>Frontend>Default>Template>Page>HTML>footer.phtml
   (outcommented some lines without results)
3. App>Design>Frontend>Default>Template>Layout(outcommented footer_links lines without luck)
4. Backend:System>Config>General-Design>(changed footer, but the text added in this part will only add text before the turnkey link)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already scanned the whole source code of your Magento installation by a concise pattern like "Turnkey", e.g. by using `grep -r "Turnkey" /path/of/your/mage/install`?

Comment: Googling a bit show that this seems to be some weird [Apache setting](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20090827/footer-powered-turnkey-linux#comment-1686), or a [CSS setting](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20090827/footer-powered-turnkey-linux)

Comment: @JürgenThelen Great, I had to delete the lines in the apache directory. Thanks! The link in the footer disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Well since I encountered the same problem, the answer lies in the file **substitute.conf** in /etc/apache2/**mods-available**

Empty this file and you are done !

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress users: in case if you don't have access to apache files, or want to turn off this Turnkey credit footer only in your wordpress site, add this to your wordpress theme's style.css:

```
/** Credit info in footer removal for TurnKey Linux */
#turnkey-credit  { 
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the Apache mod_substitute for something else (which most likely you aren't), then the easiest/best way to remove it is simply disable the Apache module (which is what is adding it).

```
a2dismod substitute
service apache2 restart
```

If you do remove the credit footer though, please make sure that you support TurnKey in some other way. E.g. signup to the backup service ([TKLBAM](https://hub.turnkeylinux.org/tour/backup/)), etc.